# GET URL with two variables

Tags: php, get

This goes to a target page and fills in a form field with the value of the variable `dropdownText`

```
 window.location.replace("http://example.com/new_view.cgi?ticket_type=11111&F_14115="+dropdownText);
```

To fill **two** fields, from variables `dropdownText` and `inputvalue`, this doesn't work:

window.location.replace("http://example.com/new_view.cgi?ticket_type=11111&F_14115="+dropdownText&subject="+inputvalue);

If there weren't variables involved, this would work, to put `enterThisOne` and `enterThisTwo` in the respective fields:

window.location.replace("http://example.com/new_view.cgi?ticket_type=11111&F_14115=enterThisOne&subject=enterThisTwo);

So I know how to pick up a variable and send it to fill a field, and I know how to fill two fields with text, but I don't know how to fill two fields with two variables. How can I do this? I think it's just the syntax I'm missing but I can't find it.

**UPDATE:**

Based on the answer below, this is what worked:

```
window.location.replace("http://example.com/new_view.cgi?ticket_type=15932&F_14115="+dropdownText+"&subject="+inputvalue );
```

I was really just missing the `+"` between the two field/variable pairs, the answer below made it more clear how this works.

I did it this way because the base URL includes the ticket type; my modifications, based on user input, start after that.

I'll look into escaping the variables and learn about that next, but this is great for right now; the user input is pretty standardized and shouldn't contain anything problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with URLs and variables and everything to do with JavaScript string syntax.

After `+dropdownText` you need to get back to string literal for `&subject=`

Like this:

```
window.location.replace("http://example.com/new_view.cgi" +
    "?ticket_type=11111" +
    "&F_14115=" + dropdownText +
    "&subject=" + inputvalue );
```

But you also need to properly escape your variables, or somebody can break your URL by including (e.g.) a "&" character.  For this, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: This is perfect. That's kind of what I meant, that I could sense it was just about code syntax. I'll put more in an update above. Thanks a lot.